Error in getting payload using Shopify Standard Events for web pixel related to Checkout area
I am using a code snippet provided into the docummentation for the different standard events to get the payload. But they are throiwing error into the extension. Please advise if someone face this issue before
URL for standard events:
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/web-pixels-api/standard-events
Error:
Could not resolve "@shopify/web-pixels-extension"
Trying to get the payload to check data into the deifferent standard events

Are you using this code snippet in the shopify app?
